Tab visibility on built-in tab component
I would like to use the built-in tab component (deprecated or new) & only show a tab to a specific audience.
For example, if I have a tab with a component on it that is only visible to a certain audience, I don't want the tab to show at all for users who aren't part of the audience.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H6VzyUAF/allow-conditional-tabs-for-lightning-app-builder-tab-component
